# Creating a 'file of file names' (fofn) with terminal

Tags: linux, file-format

I'm very new to Linux. Does anyone help me to explain what does a "file-of-file-names (fofn)" mean and how can I create fofn  with the full path of each file?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests the FOFN file contains an absolute path to specific set of files eg. files within a directory etc.

I believe there is a myriad of ways on how to create this kind of file. So, for example, to create FOFN file on the entire `/etc` directory one may execute:

```
# find /etc/ -type f > my_new_FOFN.txt
```

This will create a file called `my_new_FOFN.txt` containing a full-path a.k.a absolute path to each file within /etc/ directory recursively.